# Doubt on justification for measurability of a function.

Tags: functions, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

So, I was working on an exercise and I got stuck on trying to prove that a given function was measurable and I took a look at the solutions.

The function at cause is the following:
\begin{equation*}
f_n:\left[\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}\right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \hspace{.1cm} \text{ s.t. } \hspace{.1cm} f_n(x) = x^{-1/2} 
\end{equation*}
this being for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n \geq 1$.

Now, the justification given for the measurability of each $f_n(x)$ is that we have that $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is open and thus measurable (for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$).

**What I understand/not understand.** I recon that an open set surely is a measurable one, but I don't see how we apply that to this case. From my point of view, which might be wrong, $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ gives us a set of real values for each different $n$. Now, how does this composse a set? How can we look at a "set" of real values/numbers and say it is open?

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: I only see the definition of $f_n(x)$. How is $f(x)$ defined?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. $f: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(x) = x^{-1/2}$

Comment: So $f$ and $f_n$ only differ by their domains?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: And it should be $f_n : [\frac1n, 1-\frac1n] \to \mathbb R$, not $f: \cdots$?

Comment: $f_n(x)=x^{-1/2}$ is continuous on $[\frac1n, 1-\frac1n]$ and therefore measurable.

Comment: Yes, @md2perpe it should. Edited it, thanks.

Comment: I understand that continuity of the function sufficies the measuribility, altough I don't understand the justification given in the solutions, which is the one I stated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, it is enough to show that the function is continuous.
Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces (in your case $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$).

$f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous iff for all open sets $O\subset Y$, $f^{-1}(O)$ is open.

Now, the solution does not claim this is true for all open sets, but just for the sets $(a,\infty)$.
However, this is enough:

Let $S$ be a subbase of the topology on $Y$. Then, a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous iff for all $O\in S$, $f^{-1}(O)$ is open.

Finally, the collection $\{(a,\infty):a\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is a subbase for the (standard) topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I guess that does it.. Thanks!